# Multiplayer API with Unity 3.5 and AS3

Tags: flash, unity, networking, actionscript-3, actionscript

On the faq for the current preview release, http://unity3d.com/unity/preview/faq it says that while networking is not currently supported for flash compilation, we can write our own in AS3 using the Flash API. I can't seem to find the docs for this API or figure out the right way to work in both AS3 and Unity. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://playerio.com/. Very nice and relatively easy network multiplayer library with both flash and unity support.

Comment: That doesn't seem to answer the question?

Comment: bummzack is correct, while this may be something to consider, the main issue here is how to integrate actionscript with Unity -- whether I need to export to flash first, edit the generated as files, then rebuild in something like FlashDevelop or what. I just want to make sure I do it right.

Comment: Oh woops, seems like I misunderstood

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to a thread on the Unity3D forums, where some progress seems to be being made towards the end:

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/116650-UnityShared.swc-Communicating-between-Unity-Flash-Content-and-AS3.

Answer (score -2):

I'm having the same issue I'm currently creating a wrapper class for Scoreoid follow are blog I hope to have it done today.

About Scoreoid - http://www.scoreoid.net/
Scoreoid, developed by game developers for game developers, is a non-restrictive, reliable and easy to use gaming platform designed to handle but not limited to scoring, leaderboards and game management, including advanced functions such as platform content awareness, for multi-platform games.

Almog

Comment: Just wanted to update this currently the Unity Flash export does not support networking this will be updated in one of the next versions. You can use SWF communication for this however I found this a bit over complex for something that should be simple. 

If you need Unity examples you can check the wiki -http://wiki.scoreoid.net/api/score/createscore/ 

Have both JS and C# examples using the Unity WWW class.